# Facebook Marketing API Authorization

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building an internal app for a client of mine (an ad agency) who wants to do ad performance reporting for about 30 of their clients.  Part of this project is to pull down performance metrics from Facebook Ads for these 30 clients.

I've created a Facebook App and got a development token.  With this token, I've been able to get the technical part of the project working -- I can pull down the metrics just fine using Facebook's Marketing API.

My question is about authorization and authentication.  I'm thoroughly confused by Facebook's mechanisms for this.

What do I need to do to get access to Marketing API metrics for these 30 clients?

**Do I need to publish a Facebook App?**  If so, do I need to go through the approval process?  This seems kind of crazy because Facebook wants a login so they can test things out, but the product is strictly internal so there's really nothing they can log in and see.

I guess another question is: **Is there another way I can get access to these 30 clients?**  With Google Adwords, it was easy.  I just used oauth and am granted access as needed.  Is there a simple way like that with the Facebook Marketing API?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921

Comment: Thanks @CBroe!  Would you mind submitting that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @LukeEhresman I'm doing something similar. Did you write an article about process? Do you have a public git repo for this?

Comment: No. I could never get it working properly. Facebooks api is terrible. At least it was 4 years ago. I haven’t played with it since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to submit your app for review, if you want to be able to ask all users for the permission.

If your app is used by a limited number of people only, that you can add to a role in the app - then they can be asked for all permissions, even without review. This is mainly for testing purposes, but Facebook has it documented as a kind of “loophole” for apps that are only used by a limited user base. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921

Comment: so give each of 30 agency clients an app role? This sidesteps need for app review?

Comment: @GeoffLangenderfer no, that probably won’t work any more these days. Facebook has introduced further restrictions since then, to try and limit misuse.

Comment: so I likely will need to set up an llc and verify myself as a business?

Comment: @GeoffLangenderfer yes, if you develop apps for agency clients, I suppose that is the way to go. Individual verification probably does not fit that use case; plus that one is currently on pause, due to Covid according to Facebook, https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2020/03/24/pausing-individual-verification/